# Data Abstraction in Scala

Tags: scala

[image]We were given a problem in scala to define a procedure that that takes a line segment as an argument and returns its midpoint(the point whose coordinates are the average of the coordinates of the end points.) When I try to compile the program it gives me two errors, namely type mismatch errors in my midpointSegment method. I don't get why it requires a String. Can anyone point out my mistake? Below is my code.

```scala
class Point(x: Int, y: Int) {
  def xCoord = x
  def yCoord = y    

  def makeString(m: Point) = "Point" + "(" + x + "," + y + ")" 
}

class LineSegment(x: Point, y: Point) {
  def startSeg = x
  def endSeg = y

  def midpointSegment(m: LineSegment) = ((startSeg + m.startSeg) / 2, 
    (endSeg + m.endSeg) / 2)

  def makeString(m: LineSegment) = 
    "LineSegment" + "(" + x.makeString(x) + "," + y.makeString(y) + ")"
}

object Mp5 {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {   
    val aLine1 = new Point(1, 2)
    val aLine2 = new Point(5, 4)
    val aLineSegment1 = new LineSegment(aLine1, aLine2)
    val aLineSegment2 = new LineSegment(new Point(-3, 5), new Point(8, -1))

    println(aLine1.makeString(aLine1))
    println(aLine2.makeString(aLine2))
    println(aLineSegment1.makeString(aLineSegment1)) 
    println(aLineSegment2.makeString(aLineSegment2))

    println(aLineSegment1.midpointSegment(aLineSegment2))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to add two points, since `startSeg` and `m.startSeg` are points. You haven't defined how to do this, so the compiler seems to think you are adding strings (since anything can be added to a string, as in definition of `toString`). To be honest, I wouldn't expect this error if that's the entire code, and instead something about a missing `+` method.

For future reference: 1. provide the actual error message and stack trace; 2. you don't need to define methods like `def xCoord = x` in Scala, just write `val x` instead of simply `x` in class parameters; 3. read about case classes.

Comment: Is it possible that I can make a separate midPoint method to calculate the midpoint for two points then call that method for my midpointSegment method? 

Like this:    

    def midPoint(m: Point) = ((xCoord + m.xCoord) / 2, 
  (yCoord + m.yCoord)/ 2)

    def midpointSegment(m: Point) = midPoint(endSeg, m.endSeg)

although it gives me an error is there anyway to implement this correctly?

Comment: You need to write `def midPoint(m: Point) = new Point((xCoord + m.xCoord) / 2, (yCoord + m.yCoord) / 2)`. You are returning just a pair of `Int`s.

Comment: when I tried that, the compiler says it can't find the values xCoord and yCoord

Comment: Is this definition inside `class Point`?

Comment: Nope, If I placed that in class Point I would still need another midpoint function which I think should be placed in class LineSegment to get the midpoints of the endpoints of two linesegments

Comment: Then what do you expect first `xCoord` to refer to in `xCoord + m.xCoord`?

Comment: Also, no you wouldn't need another midpoint function; you would need to call this midpoint method two times instead.

Comment: How do I do that? The test result our instructor gave us was able to print out (6, 1) with println(aLineSegment1.midpointSegment(aLineSegment2))

Comment: I can't see how to help you more without directly providing a solution, which wouldn't help you learn (and your instructor wouldn't be happy with it either!).